# When trying to add margin to an element, only margin-top works

Tags: javascript, css, css-position, margin

I have a wrapper class and then a class for the content itself.

The html structure is like this

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
    // Content
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(232, 232, 237, 0.9);
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 9999;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```
.content {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: auto;
    width: 800px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 25px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 22px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

The position of the content is set by js which just centers it in the viewport. If the content is larger than the viewport, the user can scroll but the bottom of the content touches the bottom of the page.

I tried adding margin to the bottom of the content and adding a padding to the wrapper element. If I add margin to the top of the content it works, but not the bottom. Adding padding-bottom to the wrapper also has no effect.

Comment: Your Html code would be nice to see. Furthermore read about [position: absolute and fixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: it seems like it is a problem related with `position: absolute;`. Can you share your HTML?

Comment: The main problem you're facing is due to the fact that the `.content` is absolutely positioned, causing it to be taken out of the normal flow of the document, therefore not affecting the document layout. I cannot answer because I don't know about your JS file, but it seems like this is the issue here.

Comment: Margin works only if there are two elements together. Margin bottom doesn't works because there is no another element under this `.content'`element. If you want to give space use `padding-bottom` instead

Comment: @ErhanÇapar Right I see. But the wrapper element does grow downwards as the content size increases?

Comment: @NojusC That is not because your `.wrapper` is making room for `.content` but because `.content` is enlarging the height of your document, causing `.wrapper` element to set its height according to that (because you set `height: 100%;`).